# Prolog: find a path from root tree node to a specified node

Tags: tree, prolog

I have a tree for example like this:

```
root(atom).
node(atom, [cactus, butter]).
node(butter, []).
node(cactus, [home, tree, focus]).
node(home, []).
node(tree, []).
node(focus, []).
```

I would like to find a path for a specific node?
How can I achieve this?

I have a code like this:

```
path(Start, Start, _, [Start]). 
path(Start, Destination, Visited, [Start|Nodes]) :-
    \+ member(Start, Visited),
    dif(Start, Destination),
    node(Start, [Node| _]), 
    path(Node, Destination, [Start|Visited], Nodes).
```

But if works only for the request by using the first child node only.
What I mean is:
for

```
?-path(atom, home, Path).
```

I get this, which is absolutely correct

```
Path = [atom, cactus, home]
```

But if I do request like this

```
?-path(atom, butter, Path).
```

I get

```
false
```

which is obviously wrong.
I can see where the problem is - it's here `node(Start, [Node| _])`, but haven't got a clue how to fix it to take into account all the child nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer: First I need path/3 to run your query, because you defined path/4:

```
path(Start, End, Path) :-
    path(Start, End, [], Path).
```

The argument 3 in path/4 states that there is no current visited nodes.

```
path(Start, Start, _, [Start]). 
path(Start, Destination, Visited, [Start|Nodes]) :-
    \+ member(Start, Visited),
    dif(Start, Destination),
    node(Start, Etc),
    member(Node, Etc),
    path(Node, Destination, [Start|Visited], Nodes).
```

To allow path/4 to go to any node connected to the start node, I use member/2. It states that Node is any node member of the list Etc. Et voilà !

```
?- path(atom, butter, P).
P = [atom,butter]
```

Comment: See: [memberchk/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=memberchk/2)

Comment: memberchk is more performant but has its problems  memberchk/2 does not perform a full list typecheck. I would optimize later.

Comment: Specifically, the first argument to `memberchk/2` here is always a free variable. In this case `memberchk/2` will succeed deterministically with the first element of the list. If the only path from `Start` to `Destination` goes though some other than the first element, that version wouldn't find it. @GuyCoder is simply mistaken in this case, I believe.